# What is the difference between I had been and I was?

Tags: difference

I would like to know the difference between I had been and I was, in these two examples.

1. I had been a teacher for years but now I am a writer.
2. I was a teacher for years but now I am a writer.

If there anything wrong in the examples please correct me?

Comment: Honestly, they read nearly identical to me.  The first is very slightly more awkward to me as it seems to imply the past/present comparison more, but that could just be my feeling alone.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us (not in comments but in your question) what you think is the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is incorrect.  "I had been" is talking about the past of the past.

For example.  "Eight months ago I joined the army.  I had been a teacher for years before that, but I decided I needed to get more exercise."

"Eight months ago" is the past. And "years before that" is the past of that past.

Comment: Is this correct? I had been a teacher for ten years before I became a writer.

Comment: Yes, that is correct (except for capitalization and punctuation).